# VBA loop through cells and change characters to ascii code

Tags: excel, vba

I have to split string to separate cells for every character, then convert characters to their ASCII code. For this purpose I'm using ASC() but my problem is that only first row is translated to ASCII code, then I get:

> Invalid procedure call or argument

I'm just learning VBA so I don't know if that's a proper way to do it.

My code:

```
Sub check_is_prime()
 For i = 1 To 1000
    For b = 2 To 26
    Cells(i, b) = Asc(Cells(i, b).Value)
    Next b
 Next i
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Not to question your apparent interest in the ASCII character set but 1) Asc doesn't return a character code for characters that are in the ASCII character set, it returns the character code for a character in the user's "ANSI code page". 2) VBA and Excel don't use ANSI codepages directly. They use the [Unicode](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/index.html) character set. When you use Asc or Chr, it converts to/from the ANSI code page. So, I would encourage you to use `AscW` and `ChrW` and—if and when you really need to—learn the relationship between Unicode and ASCII.

Comment: Good to know, it needs to be in ASCII because that's an exam question I'm preparing for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
Sub check_is_prime()
    For i = 1 To 1000
       For b = 2 To 26
           If Cells(i, b) <> "" Then
               Cells(i, b) = Asc(Cells(i, b))
           End If
       Next b
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: IT'S WORKING! So the problem was with empty cells ?

Comment: @WinithePooh  must be.