# VBA Convert Column of Text to ASCII Values

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to convert a column of text to ASCII.  This question is similar to the linked question, but for full strings rather than individual characters.  I'm using the code below.  I don't get any error messages, just no change.  Please assume that I have no VBA Coding experience.

```
Sub Convert_ASCII()
'

Dim last As Long
Dim i As Integer
Dim l As Long
Dim s As String

last = ActiveSheet.Cells(2, "A").End(xlDown).Row

    For i = 2 To last
    s = Cells(i, 1)
        For l = 1 To Len(s)
        Mid(s, l, 1) = Asc(Mid(s, l, 1))
      Next l
   Next i
End Sub
```

[Loop to Convert Characters to ASCII](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49718839/vba-loop-trough-cells-and-change-characters-to-ascii-code)

Comment: `mid` is readonly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are converting the whole string but you are never asssigning the converted string to the cell.

```
Sub Convert_ASCII()
    '
    Dim last As Long
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim l As Long
    Dim s As String
    Dim cs As String

    last = ActiveSheet.Cells(2, "A").End(xlDown).Row

    For i = 2 To last
        s = Cells(i, 1)
        cs = ""
        For l = 1 To Len(s)
            cs = cs & Asc(Mid(s, l, 1))
        Next l
        Cells(i, 1) = cs
    Next i
End Sub
```